# Getting error on while importing webdriver in pycharm"No matching distribution found for webdriver"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

Getting error while importing webdriver in pycharm

"No matching distribution found for webdriver"

Using Pip version 20.0.2, Selenium version – 3.141.0, OS –windows &  Python 3.7

Problem mentioned [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su8ls.png) in image.

Tried cmd pip install webdriver and tried pip3 install webdriver still getting error.

I can run my script through IDLE but not through pycharm .

Answer (score 0):

You can install selenium in pycharm:

```
Pycharm -> Perform (Cntrl + Alt + S) -> Select Project Interpreter -> Click on (+) icon -> Search for Selenium -> Select and Install Package -> Apply -> Ok
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that you are probably working in an automatic virtual environment. To install libraries there, you need to open a terminal from the Pycharm environment. Open it in the bottom corner, and then just `pip install`.
Then, you will be able to access the library in your configuration.

Edit: for some reason I didn't read you can start it from IDLE, you can probably ignore the rest.

---

If you want to use the Selenium webdriver, you need to import it from the Selenium library: it's not a standalone package. Since you have already installed it, you should:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
```

And then, to check if it works, you may for example:

```py
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('stackoverflow.com')
```

You may need to install the Webdriver for your browser, though.
Check your browser version and then download the according Webdriver - remembering to go for the same version of your browser.

For Chrome, the download page is [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads).
The constructor assumes that the Webdriver is accessible in your PATH environment variable: if you don't want to set it, you can pass the path of the Webdriver to the constructor in this way:

```py
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable='path/to/webdriver')
```